# Mongodb get ONLY the matching object from a document when query

Tags: mongodb

I have a mongodb database from mongoimport which look likes this

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("5c209db2f6ba74c0f93709b7"),
"issues" : [ 
    {
        "id" : 20393,
        "project" : {
            "id" : 309,
            "name" : "Name 1"
        }
    },
    {
        "id" : 30392,
        "project" : {
            "id" : 250,
            "name" : "Name 2"
        }
    }
]
```

}

I use this query:

```
db.tickets.find({"issues.project.id":309})
```

which returns me the whole document. 
I tried using

```
db.tickets.find( { "issues.project.id":309  }, {"issues":1} )
```

But I get the same things, or I just want the Object which match in the list not the entire document.

Is it possible in mongodb or should I update the structure of the database?

Thanks for all

Comment: Try this `db.tickets.find({"issues.project.id":309}).project({ issues: 1 })`

Answer (score 1):

By updating the projection you can collect data as per your requirement. You can use like this:

```
db.tickets.find({
  "issues.project.id": 309
},
{
  "issues.$": 1
})
```

Comment: But use caution:   The $ operator will simply return the first matching item in the array.   If project.id was NOT unique , then the projection above might miss the second or more matching issues.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a slightly safer way that works if the lookup field is not unique.  We "overwrite" the original `issues` array with the filtered version:

```
db.foo.aggregate([
{$match: {"issues.project.id": 309}}
,{$project: { issues: { $filter: {
            input: "$issues",
            as: "z",
            cond: { $eq: [ "$$z.project.id", 309 ] }
        }}
}}
```